# Dashcode CurrencyConverter App

Tags: ios-simulator, dashcode

I was working on CurrencyConverterApp in Dashcode by following this url. http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/build-web-apps-iphone-using-dashcode. But in code i am geting an error

[Session started at 2010-09-08 14:55:29 +0530]
mobile/main.js line 146: SyntaxError: Parse error
mobile/index.html line 14: Can't find variable: load
[Session ended at 2010-09-08 14:55:37 +0530].

Please help me in this code to complete my App.

Answer (score 0):

Most possible you have an error in the script file (main.js). Double check your code if you have closed a { or } or something else. You can also use this online tool to help you out: http://www.jslint.com/